# Как получить список доступных точек Wifi на Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, wifi

В Qt есть некая библиотека — "B2QtWifi", к сожалению она является комерческой.
А на форумах пишут, что реализовать данную задачу можно используя WinApi с помощью функции "WlanGetAvailableNetworkList".

Как в Qt можно реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: Не пытайтесь программировать исключительно на Qt. Qt просто фрейморк (набор библиотек). Используйте winapi'шную функцию, если пишите на винде, или подобную функцию на другой ОС.

Comment: Я с вами согласен на все 100%, только я не пишу под Windows, но сейчас возникла такая одноразовая задача. Как для одной маленькой задачи слишком много времени приходится тратить, сама установка Visual Studio занимает не мало времени и пространства на диске. Ну раз уж нет альтернатив, придется ставить VS. Не хотелось бы идти такм длинным путём.

Comment: А `QNetworkConfigurationManager` не пробовали? У него есть возможность получить список сетей и вроде даже выделить среди них беспроводные.

Answer (score 1):

На `Qt` используйте примерно следующий код (NB: на работоспособность не тестировал!):

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager netManager;
foreach (const QNetworkConfiguration& netConfig, netManager.allConfigurations()) {
  if (netConfig.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN) {
    // I'm wireless network
    if (netConfig.type() == QNetworkConfiguration::InternetAccessPoint) {
      // I'm access point
    }
  }
}
```